# Angular reactive forms patchValue does not work on ngbDatepicker input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ng-bootstrap

I'm patching my reactive form with data I receive from my backend.

```
 getUpdate(id: number) {
    this.httpService.getUpdate(this.environment, id).subscribe({
      next: (response: Update) => {
        this.update = response;

        this.updateForm.patchValue({
          channel: response.channel,
          updateTo: response.updateTo,
          updateOptionalUntil: response.updateOptionalUntil,
          setupFile: response.setupFile,
          information: response.information,
          md5: response.md5
        }) 
      }
    })
  }
```

This works fine if I have a "plain" text-field, like that:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
     <span class="input-group-text" for="updateOptionalUntil">Optional until</span>
     <input class="form-control" id="updateOptionalUntil" type="text" formControlName="updateOptionalUntil">
</div>
```

Now, I would like to add a ngbDatepicker to update that input field, but as soon as I add it, my patch-value does not work anymore and the field stays empty when the component loads.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
     <span class="input-group-text" for="updateOptionalUntil">Optional until</span>
     <input class="form-control" id="updateOptionalUntil" type="text" formControlName="updateOptionalUntil" ngbDatepicker #updateOptionalUntil="ngbDatepicker">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="updateOptionalUntil.toggle()"><i class="fa-light fa-calendar-days"></i></button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried manual force update on the view? declare it in consturctor `cdr: ChageDetectionRef` and call `this.cdr.detectChanges();` after patch/setValue()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the **[DOC](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#date-model)**.

> Datepicker uses NgbDateStruct interface as a model and not the native
> Date object.

You should convert your string to `NgbDateStruct` format

```
 correctValue: NgbDateStruct ={
    year:2022,
    month:12,
    day:13
  };
```

**[Working Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdg8d1?file=src/app/datepicker-popup.html)**

Comment: Thank you, i thought the input remains a simple text-field and I would only have to convert the value I get from the Datepicker. 

Is there an easy way to convert a string like "yyyy-MM-dd" into a NgbDateStruct?
Im currently doing sth like this:

let dateFormatted: NgbDateStruct = {
          year: parseInt(response.updateOptionalUntil.substring(0,4)),
          month: parseInt(response.updateOptionalUntil.substring(5,7)),
          day: parseInt(response.updateOptionalUntil.substring(8,10))
        }

Comment: @reveN, You can use regular expresions:`const match=response.updateOptionalUntil.match(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/);dateFormated:NgbDateStruct={year:+match[1],month:+match[2],day:+match[3]}`

Comment: not sure if thats an "easy" way, but it works :D

Comment: @reveN  There are multiple way you can convert one solution is as suggested by Elliseo use regex. or you can convert the string to date object and extract individual properties. I have updated stackblitz please check.